# Combining SOCAT with SSH to have dynamic port forwarding through socks proxy

Tags: ssh, socks, socat

My issue is very simple, what I want to do is to connect to my ssh through socat, this means if I have server 10.0.0.1 that has SSH and SOCAT together I listen to 5555 port of my socat, then my socat forwards all tcp packets to my ssh server 22 port for dynamic port forwarding.

I hope hear from you and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic configuration that seems to be what you want.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5555 TCP:localhost:22
```

If you want to use ssh on the server as a SOCKS proxy then you don't need socat. On the server run

```
ssh -D 10.0.0.1:5555 localhost
```

Of course it is more secure if you run the ssh client on your local machine and change your socks proxy to point to localhost using

```
ssh -D 5555 10.0.0.1
```

on the client machine.

If you can only use ssh indirectly then you can combine the above by running ssh on the server listening to 5550 on localhost and having socat listening on 5555 and forwarding it to 5550:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:5555,fork TCP:localhost:5550 &
ssh -N -D 5550 localhost
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, i tried this before, but once I change my firefoxe's socks proxy config to listen to 10.0.0.1 on port 5555 then I get conneciton refused in my server.

Comment: Hi Bill, I don't wanna use ssh directly because of overload data, my project 's requirements needs me to use pure socks server for dynamic tcp port forwarding.

Comment: So you can't use ssh at all or you just can't use it directly?

Comment: I can't use it directly.

Comment: I don't think this fixes any data overload problem. All your browser web traffic will go through that proxy,  also ssh -D running on the server has no security so anyone else with access to that server could be using the socks proxy and inflating your data usage.

Comment: thank a lot, i will try it when I have a time then report you. Thank you